# DomainError using Julia DifferentialEquations

Tags: julia, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs using Julia's DifferentialEquations package, but I'm getting a DomainError when using the Euler method which I don't understand why.

The system looks like this:

```
function ice(du, u, p, t)
    εₘ, εₖ, σ, F, d, ε = u
    Aₘ, Qₘ, n, pₘ, R, T, Eₖ, Eₘ, η, dₛₛ, Fₛₛ, ε₁, ε₂, S  = p
    
    du[1] = Aₘ * (σ/F)^n * d^(-pₘ) * ℯ^(-Qₘ/(R*T))
    du[2] = (σ - Eₖ*εₖ)/η
    du[3] = Eₘ*(S - ((σ - Eₖ*εₖ)/η) - (Aₘ * (σ/F)^n * d^(-pₘ) * ℯ^(-Qₘ/(R*T))))
    du[4] = S*(Fₛₛ - F)/ε₁
    du[5] = S*(dₛₛ - d)/ε₂
    du[6] = S
end
```

The parameter values are:

```
p = [0.7, 70.0, 3.5, 0.35, 8.315, 265.0, 4.0e9, 9.0e9, 1.0e11, 0.00025, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0e-6]
```

Initial conditions:

```
u_0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.001, 0.0]
```

Then using:

```
tspan = (0, 100)
prob = ODEProblem(ice, u_0, tspan, p)
sol = solve(prob, Euler() , dt = 0.001 ,reltol = 1e-4)
```

I get the error:

```
DomainError with -1.4975890818396533e11:
Exponentiation yielding a complex result requires a complex argument.
Replace x^y with (x+0im)^y, Complex(x)^y, or similar.
```

Which I'm not sure why because the value in the exponent term in the equations is fixed and close to 1 with the above parameters.

Comment: If you want to raise a negative number to a negative non-integer power you need to use complex numbers (like in d^(-pₘ))

Comment: I understand, but this term is positive. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Why? The initial condition is positive, but I assume that doesn't mean d is always positive

Comment: Because its derivative will change sign as soon as it reaches the value of the ```d_ss``` parameter, which is positive too. This makes sure the value will not go below ```d_ss``` significantly (this is equation ```du[5]```.

Comment: Ah ok well in this case it looks like it's σ/F that becomes negative

Comment: For the same reason, this term is positive too. That's why I asked the question

Comment: I mean I ran it myself and it definitely is negative